# flutter : not able to display image from firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]I am trying to get array of images to be displayed on container widget which is stored in firebase firestore. The url is stored with index in firestore and cloud storage. Here is the complete code below. I followed the code provided online, I am not sure what I am missing or where I went wrong. pls help me out.Thanks in advance.

```
 class NewImage extends StatefulWidget{

 List<String> urls;
 int currentIndex;
 VoidCallback onImageTap;

NewImage({Key key,@required this.urls,@required this.currentIndex,@required this.onImageTap})
  :super(key:key);

  @override
 _NewImage createState() => _NewImage();
 }

 class _NewImage extends State<NewImage>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{


 List<String> images = [];
 final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 final FirebaseFirestore fb = FirebaseFirestore.instance;


 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getImages();
}



   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 160.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0,horizontal: 15.0),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getImages(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          leading: Image.network(
                              snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["images"],
                              fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        );


                      });
                } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                  return Text("No data");
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),

          ),


        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


}

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getImages()  async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(
      auth.currentUser.uid).collection("images").get();
}

  }
```

Comment: What does your firebase structure look like? Do you have an array of links where the images are stored or what do you mean by "stored in firebase firestore"?

Comment: yes they are array of links with index value like 0 then its url,1 then its url and so on under "images" collection

Comment: and now getting this error: W/DynamiteModule(20853): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0 W/ProviderInstaller(20853): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0. Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)

Comment: pls check I have uploaded pic.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing array to networkImage instead of image

change it like this

```
Image.network(
      snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["images"][index],// [index] added
      fit: BoxFit.fill),
```

Comment: thanks for reply but now getting the following error:W/DynamiteModule(20853): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(20853): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0. Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)

Comment: pls check I have uploaded pic

Comment: if you are using flutterfire then use cloud_firestore cause this seems to be issue 
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4447

Comment: As @MoaidALRazhy suggested with the previous link, try to clean the project and rebuild it. Please tell us if that worked for you, future users could benefit from your response. If not, we will help you further.